# How to decrease a value of a variable based on a user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can usually find the answer to questions without posting but I'm completely stuck here so I appreciate any help.

I am creating a cost calculator using Javascript & jQuery which needs to be able to give discounts based on the number of licences entered. My costs for the calculator are as follows:

- 1-49 Licences = £50 per licence (this is nice and simple)
- 50 - 249 Licences = Starts at £49.90 per licence but the per licence cost will decrease by 0.10 for each additional licence. For example 50 licences would cost £49.90 per licence, 51 licences would cost 49.80 per licence and so on.
- 250+ Licences = No calculation, a message will be displayed to call.

**My Question:** I have created a LicenceCost variable to store the cost per licence which I can use for calculation. How can I set this variable to account for the 0.10 discount for each licence above 49?

All the articles I have read recommend to use multiple if...else statements which I don't think works well in my case as I would have 200 of them for a little calculator. I might have gone about this the wrong way so if I need to take a different approach I'm open to ideas and I will happily start again!

Thanks for any help, I have included a snippet below for reference.

**Note**: The cost calculator is not being used for any payments, it's just for illustration so I am not concerned about doing this client side.

```js
$('#NumberOfLicencesInput').bind('input', function() {
  // Get number of selected licences
  var SelectedLicences = document.getElementById('NumberOfLicencesInput').value;

  // Output number of selected licences
  document.getElementById("NumberOfLicencesOutput").innerHTML = SelectedLicences;

  // if selected number of licences is less than 50 then the licence cost is 50 and the total cost is calculated
  if (SelectedLicences < 50) {
    LicenceCost = 50;
    TotalCost = LicenceCost * SelectedLicences;
    document.getElementById("TotalCost").innerHTML = TotalCost
  }
  // if selected number of licences is more than 49 then the licence cost should starts at 49.90 but should decrease by 0.10 for each additional licence I.E 50 = 49.90, 51 = 49.80 etc...
  else if (SelectedLicences > 49 && SelectedLicences < 250) {
    LicenceCost = 49.90;
    TotalCost = LicenceCost * SelectedLicences;
    document.getElementById("TotalCost").innerHTML = TotalCost
  }
  // if 250 or above display a message to call
  else {
    document.getElementById("TotalCost").innerHTML = "Please Call";
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="NumberOfLicencesInput"></input>
<div>
  <p>
    Number of Licences:
    <b id="NumberOfLicencesOutput"></b>
  </p>
  <p>
    Total Cost:
    <b id="TotalCost"></b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LicenceCost = 50.00 - (SelectedLicences-49)*.10;` to calculate licence cost when the no. of licences is greater than 49.

Like in the below snippet.

```js
$('#NumberOfLicencesInput').bind('input', function() {
  // Get number of selected licences
  var SelectedLicences = document.getElementById('NumberOfLicencesInput').value;

  // Output number of selected licences
  document.getElementById("NumberOfLicencesOutput").innerHTML = SelectedLicences;

  // if selected number of licences is less than 50 then the licence cost is 50 and the total cost is calculated
  if (SelectedLicences < 50) {
    LicenceCost = 50;
    TotalCost = LicenceCost * SelectedLicences;
    document.getElementById("TotalCost").innerHTML = TotalCost
  }
  // if selected number of licences is more than 49 then the licence cost should starts at 49.90 but should decrease by 0.10 for each additional licence I.E 50 = 49.90, 51 = 49.80 etc...
  else if (SelectedLicences > 49 && SelectedLicences < 250) {
    // this does the trick
    LicenceCost = 50.00 - (SelectedLicences-49)*.10;
    console.log(LicenceCost); // just to log value to console
    TotalCost = LicenceCost * SelectedLicences;
    document.getElementById("TotalCost").innerHTML = TotalCost
  }
  // if 250 or above display a message to call
  else {
    document.getElementById("TotalCost").innerHTML = "Please Call";
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="NumberOfLicencesInput"></input>
<div>
  <p>
    Number of Licences:
    <b id="NumberOfLicencesOutput"></b>
  </p>
  <p>
    Total Cost:
    <b id="TotalCost"></b>
  </p>
</div>
```